# JSLint error in Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jslint

I've written a Gruntfile.js where I call `grunt.file.delete()`, and JSLint is barking at me, saying, "Expected an identifier and instead saw 'delete' (a reserved word).     `grunt.file.delete(config[task].dest);`"

`config` is an object, `task` a string matching the task name, and `dest` a path string.

I already have `/*jslint node:true */` set at the top of the file.

Does anyone know if this is a valid issue, and if it is, what's the basis and what do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/752

> If you enable the es5 option for linting your Gruntfile with JSHint, this error should go away.

Alternatively, just change `grunt.file.delete` to `grunt.file['delete']`

Comment: There's no es5 option for JSLint that I can find (JSHint's es5 option is now set by default). However, the very nice hack of grunt.file['delete']() works great, and as someone pointed out in the link you posted, it's not as sexy as the simpler syntax, but it's certainly functional. JSLint's happy now! Many thanks!